# Change body background-image onclick with images from ul

Tags: javascript, html, css, buttonclick

I want to got a body with a defined background-image and be able to choose from a ul to the background i want to change(ex:car,dog,house...).

```
body {
    width:1200px;
    height:907px;
    background-image: url("fotos/cc.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

<body>          
<select id="borde" onchange="encender();" name="select1">
            <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select>
</body>
```

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: Where is the code in function `encender()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't clearly specify what you want to do with select tag. However as I understood you want to change background image on option change. Your eventHandler is calling a function which is not created. I have called onchange event via JQuery to store background Image from selected option value in the code below.

```js
     var body = document.getElementById('body');
     var select= document.getElementById('borde');
     $('select[name=select1]').on('change', function(){
          body.style.backgroundImage =  String('url('+ select.children[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute('value')+')')
     })
```

```css
body {
    width:1200px;
    height:907px;
    background-image: url("http://cdn3.megarush.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/search-engine-friendly-urls.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id ='body'>          
<select id="borde" name="select1">
            <option value="http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg">default</option>
            <option value="https://res.cloudinary.com/ahrefs/image/upload/v1407314140/production-application-pending-logo-152.jpg">1</option>
            <option value="http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg">2</option>
            <option value="http://topwalls.net/wallpapers/2012/01/Nature-sea-scenery-travel-photography-image-768x1366.jpg">3</option>
            <option value="http://img.gettyimageslatam.com/public/userfiles/redesign/images/landing/home/img_entry_002.jpg">4</option>
          </select>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, i explained it horrible but it was what i want, thank you for the time and sorry for my bad explaining

Comment: Good. Confusing things there are that you've mentioned "ul" but the is no `ul` in your code and `onchange` event is calling `encender()` function which is not declared. Please always re-read your question before publishing.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, then you want to change the background-image of the body according to what is selected in the  tag right?

If so, then that can be accomplished through javascript with either a switch statement(shown below) or through setting the value on the option in the select tag to be a string and using the value as the background image. The first way would look something like this:

```js
function changeBackground(selectedOption) {
  var imgSRC = "";
  
  switch (selectedOption.value) {
      case "0":
        imgSRC = "dog.png";
        break;
      case "1":
        imgSRC = "cat.png";
        break;
      case "2":
        imgSRC = "house.png";
        break;
      default:
        imgSRC = "default.png";
        break;
  }
  
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + imgSRC + "')";
}
```

```html
<select id="borde" onchange="changeBackground(this);" name="select1">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```